# jQuery Ajax request over SSL

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl, https

So I am using the following code to send an ajax request

```
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: base_url + "/notifications/send_notification",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            action: 'action_complete',
                            entity_id: 31
                        }
                    });
```

This code works perfectly on my local machine, but when I upload it to our server (which now has SSL setup), and try doing it over https and not http, it comes up with a "500 Internal Server Error".

P.s the "base_url" variable does include the "https" url.

EDIT:
Here is a screenshot of the Network > Header tab in Chrome:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `base_url` is the website you're in, I mean if you enter your website in https://www.example.com, and `base_url` is at https://www.example.com/notifications/send_notification then try to omit `base_url` from the `url` parameter.

If `base_url` is another site then it might be some cross-site script issue.

If non of the above then it might be an issue with the server. Are you sure the SSL certificate is good? If it's self-signed then you need to "approve" it in the browser first.

Lastly, you can check the exact send/receive data with i.e Chrome, just F12 and check `Network` (must be open before the request is made).

Additionally, you could directly request that url with Fiddler (if it's POST, if it's GET then simply get into it with a browser).

Comment: So the send data seems correct, and the receive data is throwing a 404 error through the CodeIgniter system, as if I'm pointing it to the wrong URL. I'm certain though that this url is correct because I can access it through the browser url bar and it works fine.

Comment: Makre sure, in the browser, that nothing is cached. Like in Chrome you could use the "Incognito Mode". Anyway, the `Network` tab shows the real information and you should follow that. Make sure, again, that in the `Network` tab the request is NOT from the cache.

Comment: Turns out it was the CSRF variable being turned on in the CodeIgniter config. I had to include a CSRF token in the ajax post data.

Answer (score 0):

Perform network monitoring from your browser to read the body of the 500 Internal Server Error response. If you are sending JSON back make sure you apply `AllowGet: true`.

Can you post a screenshot of the response body like this:
[image]

Comment: The response I get is a 404 error page thrown from CodeIgniter. This seems to imply that I'm providing the wrong url? But it's the exact same as it would be, just with https instead of http.

Comment: Does the server perform any redirection?

Comment: I don't have any redirection that I can think of, but I am using this in my .htaccess file "RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301] "

Comment: I added a screenshot of what I'm seeing.

Comment: Try changing contentType: application/json. Also the screenshot is of the request rather than the response to this request.

Comment: Alright thanks! It seems like the request is working now with the contentType being defined. I have noticed though that variables aren't working now. I was picking up variables as $_POST through the request, but that's not working now?

Comment: Oh, and my bad with the screenshot haha :P

Comment: If you are using MVC on the server side you can define a Model to pass into your post action:
public class ActionModel
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public int Entity_Id { get; set; }
}

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand? Could you perhaps elaborate your example?

Comment: What is your server-side engine? PHP? $_POST['action'] and $_POST['entity_id'] are not defined now?

Comment: Yes. Using CodeIgniter. I understand the public class action model declaration, but what is the get; set, and public string action?

Comment: That was in terms of MVC, I was mislead you're using ASP.NET MVC when you're actually not.

Comment: Yes they are not defined apparently. No problem.

Comment: Weird! I'm not aware of how exactly JSON is deserialized with php, can you actually debug this?

Comment: It's working now. I had to change the type to "GET", and then grab that data in PHP using $_GET (or $this->input->get() with CodeIgniter). But, I don't think I'm happy with this solution, as technically I'm not "Getting" any data, just sending it. Why does this work and not "POST"?