# Best Way to Share Cookie with API to authenticate Users

Tags: php, javascript, api, security

I have edited my question and made it simple as i think its vague. So
I have made it simple.
I want to authenticate users using API using cookie stored in browser. OF course cookie changes randomly at every login.

Information knowledge : Using custom API and php at backend

And Javascript and Tempojs as templating engine frontend .

EDITED:

My algorithm goes like this:
Database has only one field which changes on every login that is login-attempt which increments every time.

When user logs in using php . Session and cookie is generated and one cookie which is used to connect to api will be

```
hash of (username + login attempt+ salt)= xxxxxxxyyyyyyxxxxxx
```

Now Api knows what the cookie value should be so it verifies that user is correct and responds to data .Now whenever user logs out cookie expires and api can no more authenticate .
What i will be using to fetch data of users i will post the

Cookie through xmlhttprequest to api server which is on different subdomain and load data into web application.

This is my plan if anyone think this method is vulnerable or insecure. Do let me know.
yes for cross domain request i will be using

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")
or 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'www.website.com'")

But if you do have alternate .Please describe i can use jsonp but i dont want to and also i might have to upload file data too .

Comment: vaque question, what kind of language, what kind of api. Can you post some code?

Comment: @Erwinus I thought the question is clear. Let me explain. I have api server for my website which only responds when a secret hash is sent to it either via get or post.
The secret hash which is generated .Only API can verify its correct or not.
For security reason that hash value changes every time when user logs in and it is stored in cookie. 
What would be your way to send that hash value to api server for communicating thought js ,as after login request to api will be done from client side only and multiple times in order to receive json data.

Comment: Like I said before, without code we are unable to help you! I understand what you are trying to do but it is not clear how you implement it, maybe your implementation is wrong.

Comment: @Erwinus Hi. i updated my question , i have described my algorithm as i havent coded it yet.

Comment: vague question like @Erwinus said, but how about using SSL? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068249/jquery-ajax-request-over-ssl

Comment: @Ejay ,Alright i have made it simpler and make it understandable . Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proposed solution sounds good. However, there are a few things that you should make sure:

- Make sure that the salt in the hash is long enough (I'd just use 32 chars to be on the safe side although that's a bit much).
- Make sure that the salt really is the last component in the hash function. If it isn't, it might be possible for attackers to create their own cookies in some cases ([here's how](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack)).
- Use a delimiter when you do the hash. For example, if there's a user `foo` and there's another user `foo1`, this would happen if you don't use a delimiter: When `foo` logs in for the 11th time, his cookie is `hash("foo11"+salt)`, and when `foo1` logs in for the first time, his cookie is `hash("foo11"+salt)`, too. That would be bad, so do something like `hash(user+"|"+login_attempt+"|"+salt)` instead.
- Your API server will also have to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header, I think.

Oh, also keep in mind that when a user logs in from computer A and then logs in from computer B, his session from computer A won't be valid anymore.

Comment: +1 for great answer.  Yes, the salt (and its length thereof) is the most important part of this whole thing because that is where the randomness comes in so that attackers can't make their own cookies.  Good call on the delimiter ;-)  Why does the salt need to be last?  Since it's all hashing anyway would that matter?  What case would an attacker be able to create their own cookies?  I'll take your word for it now, but I'm very curious.

Comment: @Freedom_Ben: I explicitly mentioned the delimiter because I've seen a vuln in a real-world system because of the omission of a delimiter. :D About the order of elements: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack to see what can happen if you don't have the secret in the last position.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  That is a fascinating and obscure attack that I've never heard of before.  Well done.

Comment: @thejh Will this be best or secure way for uploading files directly through api to server using this hash.

Comment: @AbhishekGahlot: I think I can't come up with any issues in that concept at the moment.

Comment: @thejh Great, so do i. Thats why i asked this on stackoverflow.Thanks for your great answer